# Qual a lógica por tras desse desafio?

Tags: c++, lógica

PERGUNTA:
No futebol americano, as equipes brigam por espaço em campo e fazem pontos de duas formas diferentes: através do touchdown, que pode valer 6 ou 7 pontos e através do chute ao gol, que vale 3 pontos. Quando uma equipe entra na área de touchdown do adversário, ela pontua imediatamente 6 pontos e tem direito a um chute ao gol que vale 1 ponto extra. Enfim, os placares dos jogos são montados pela possibilidade de fazer 3, 6 ou 7 pontos, o que significa que alguns placares são impossíveis de acontecer como fazer 5, 13 ou 22 pontos. Sua tarefa será ter uma coleção de placares de um time (array) e identificar se os placares são ou não possíveis de serem realizados.

Ex: 17 → placar inválido, 10 → placar válido

As condições que eu consegui foram várias, mas por se tratar de um desafio eu acredito que o código não fique grande, por isso não coloquei todas:

declarei um array com os placares. O programa apenas precisa dizer se são placares válidos ou não.

```
 int placarNY[10] = {17, 26, 22, 10, 21, 18, 15, 24, 35, 19};

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if((placarNY[i]%3 == 0) ||(placarNY[i]%7 == 0)||(placarNY[i]%10 == 0)){
        cout << placarNY[i] << " <- placar valido !" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << placarNY[i] << " <- placar invalido !" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A lógica desse desafio é verificar se existem `A`, `B` e `C` inteiros tais que `A*3 + B*6 + C*7 = P`, sendo `P` a pontuação que se deseja saber se é válida ou não

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em resumo, precisa descobrir se existem números inteiros não negativos a, b e c tais que "score=3*a+6*b+7*c". Ao invés de buscar a solução matematicamente descobrindo possíveis a, b e c, você pode usar recursão para verificar possibilidades de placares ao longo das mudanças (afinal as únicas mudanças isoladas de placares que ocorrem são aumentos de 3, aumento de 6 e aumento de 7 pontos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando num ramo a pontuação é menor que o placar que é verificado, verifica-se os inferiores. Se ao invés de menor for igual, acabou, confirmada a possibilidade de alcançar aquela pontuação. Se ao invés disso for maior, sai desse ramo e verifica outro. Se acabarem os ramos sem encontrar a soma igual ao placar verificado, então não é possível alcançar aquela pontuação.

Edit1: esqueci de falar que acumular 6 pontos é o mesmo que duas vezes acumular três, portanto não precisa ramificar com seis pontos, o de três resolve. Ramos de +3 e +7 são suficientes.

Edit2: há outra alternativa em que você assume possíveis valores de `a` (números de marcações de +3) de zero a `floor(score/3)` e calcula o `c` (número de possíveis marcações de +7). Por exemplo, para formar 15 pontos, assuma a=0,1,...,5 marcações de +3. Com a=0, temos 3*a+7*b=15 ==> b=15/7, sendo b=15/7 não inteiro e portanto solução não aceita. Com a=1, temos 3*a+7*b=15 ==> b=12/7, sendo b=12/7 solução não aceita. Daí em diante até encontrar uma solução válida que confirme a possibilidade do placar ou conferir todos e não encontrar, negando a possibilidade.

Comment: Acredito ter entendido, vou verificar aqui e aplicar no código. Qual que coisa eu aviso ! Valeu, bro!

Answer (score 0):

A lógica por trás desse desafio é uma variação do [Problema da Mochila](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila) e do [Problema de Frobenius](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_troco_de_Frobenius).

Ambos os problemas podem ser resolvidos com métodos de [Programação Dinâmica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica).